# Equivalence class in equivalence relation

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let $A=\{1,2,3,4,...,9\}$ and $R$ be a relation in $A \times A$ defined by $(a,b)R(c,d)$. If $a+d=b+c$ for $(a,b),(c,d)$ in $A \times A$. Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation and also obtain the equivalent class $(2,5)$.

I have proved it to be equivalence relation but how to find the obtain the equivalent class $(2,5)$. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Reworded, $(a,b)R(c,d)$ iff $a-b=c-d$ iff $a$ is the same distance above $b$ as $c$ is above $d$.  $2$ is three under $5$.  What other pairs are there with the first number three less than the second number?  That is all that is being asked when being asked "find the equivalence class of $(2,5)$" it is just asking "what other pairs have the first number the same distance below the second number as $(2,5)$" in this specific problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for such a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know the theorem that if $A$ is a set and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $A$, then $A$ can be split into disjoint classes under this equivalence.

The key to this theorem is the following observation:

> Two elements in the same equivalence class are related under $\sim$, while elements of different classes are *not* related under $\sim$.

That is, given an element, it's equivalence class is *precisely* the set of all elements it is related to.

Having said that, you just need to figure out all pairs of numbers $(a,b) \subset A \times A$ such that $a - b = 2-5$, with the help of the comment given above. I am sure you can do it from here.

Comment: $a-b = 2-5~~~~$

Comment: @JMoravitz Correction made, just before you posted the comment.